# failing to convert two different date types format within in datetimestamp variable, into one standard format yyyy-dd-mm using ymd()

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data set in which one of the variables is a datatimestamp column and that contains some dates in the one format and others in other format.

One such sample is show below (when executed on prompt on R):

```
 > df$InDates
```

prints

```
   "12-01-2010 14:32" ....  "3/25/2011 8:41"
```

Now if I am trying to convert these into one single format using lubridate, I am getting some converted but others are becoming NAs :

```
   >  library(lubridate)

   >  df$InDate2 <- ymd(df$InDate)

   >  df$InDate2

     "12-01-2010" ....  "NA"
```

Not sure, how to convert all these dates into one type which is YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this.
It tries to parse as date (with `as_date`) all the strings it can convert and leaves as NA the rest.
You then fill those NAs (with `coealesce`) with the other format.

The problem for you now is to be sure to know all the format you have in the data.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dates <- c("12-01-2010 14:32", "3/25/2011 8:41")

coalesce(as_date(dates, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), 
         as_date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

# [1] "2010-01-12" "2011-03-25"
```

Comment: awesome! after edit, this is working without warning.